# how to resolve the import com.facebook.Session

Tags: android, eclipse-plugin

ihave receive the error if  `

import the package

```
import com.facebook.Seesion;
import com.facebook.SessionState;
import com.facebook.UiLifecycleChangedHelper;
import com.facebook.model.GraphUser;
import com.facebook.widget.LoginButton;
import com.facebook.widget.LoginButton.UserInfoChangedCallback;
```

i am use the android sdk 4.4.2 and facebook sdk 4.5.1

[image: img]

Comment: Have you added the relevant .jar files in the lib directory?

Comment: yes i m added all relevent .jar flies

Comment: Where is the lib directory located? Check inside properties of project, if the jar files are added.

Answer (score 0):

```
in project:
```

i have face same problem like this,in my case ,i create new workspace again import all the  library files and project it works perfectly.(New facebook sdk 4.5.1)

import com.facebook.FacebookException;

import com.facebook.FacebookOperationCanceledException;

import com.facebook.Session;

import com.facebook.SessionState;

import com.facebook.UiLifecycleHelper;

import com.facebook.android.Facebook;

import com.facebook.model.GraphUser;

import com.facebook.widget.LoginButton;

hope it will help,donot consider above mentioned importing files,you just start with your project in new workspace.